# Union of two lists of enums do not produce distinct items?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

With

```
        var test = new RarityEnum[] { RarityEnum.Uncommon };
        var test2 = new RarityEnum[] { RarityEnum.Uncommon };
        var test3 = test.Union(test2);
```

Why is the test3 only containing 1 item and not 2?

How should I change this so it properly produces a new list of enums (even if the same enum value is present multiple times)?

I could cast to int before Union then cast back to enum after...is that the cleanest? I feel casting is not so pretty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Microsoft's documentation on Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Union__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__): "This method excludes duplicates from the return set. This is different behavior to the [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8) method, which returns all the elements in the input sequences including duplicates."

In this example:

```
var test = new string[] { "cat" };
var test2 = new string[] { "cat" };
var test3 = test.Concat(test2);
var test4 = test.Union(test2);
```

`test3` ends up being `{ "cat", "cat" }`

`test4` is just `{ "cat" }`